# Grid or Listview Row & column re-order WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, datagrid

how to re-order the row and column of grid and listview in wpf. please discuss. thanks

Comment: Thomas do you mean you want to be able to Drag & Drop columns and rows to move them horizontally ( columns ) and verzically ( rows ) with the mouse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns can be reorded by drag'n'drop column headers, at runtime. To reorder columns programmatic, you need to modify ListView.View's Columns collection, for example:

```
GridView gv = listview.View as GridView;
GridViewColumn cd = gv.Columns[0];
gv.Columns.Remove(cd);
gv.Columns.Add(cd);
```

(assuming listview is your ListView and its View is a GridView with at least 2 columns) this code will put the first column at the end.

To reorder rows, programmatic, you modify the Collection behind the ListView (if the ListView has no sorting, if it has one should not want to change the order of the rows).

To reorder rows by means of drag and drop, you need to write some code to handle all the beautiful events that define a drag and drop operation. An example and a starting point can be [this blog post](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop).

Also, if you provide more details of what exactly you want, we can provide more detailed answers.

Comment: it is ok for column re-order but what about row re-order. do i need to add any code for that.

Comment: Yes you need to add code. I haven't seen any built-in functionality for reordering the rows. But it's possible by handling the mouse drag events, as shown in the blog post I've indicated. Pavan Podila also has some reusable Drag'n'Drop code here: http://blog.pixelingene.com/?cat=19 that might help you, but the idea is that you need to write code for reordering rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reorder rows and to save or use the new row order I suggest you add a column called Index or RowIndex or whatever also to the underlying datasource of your control, in this way with the Drag&Drop operation you simply change the value of that column for a given row and after everything has been done you can store or use this value for the next render or whatever else you need.